# Node JS - I Can't Use FS.Stat Synchronously

Tags: node.js, fs

I have a node js function. It's checking all folders for certain files and compare every single file's last write date with request date. If there is matching one I want to store that folder's path. Actually, my function works but it's making date control Asynchronously. I try fs.statSync but it's not worked either. When I use statSync I can't get any console log output.

```
console.log('Collected Files - OutsideIF : ' + filesCollected);
```

it's not gonna showing anything to me. Not even empty one. And my last console log returns empty.

I add comments to my code. Here my function :

```
var scanFolders = function(){ 
  // Listing all directories and files in path
  fs.readdir(path,(err,files) => {
    // Creating Variable For Record Result
    var filesCollected = "";
    // Loop for every directory and file
    files.forEach(file=>{
      // If current path is a directory
      if (fs.lstatSync(path+'/'+file).isDirectory()){
        // Check that directory for certain files
        if((fs.existsSync(path+'/'+file+'/'+'LineChart.html')) && (fs.existsSync(path+'/'+file+'/'+'clip.mp4'))){
          // Check last write time for clip mp4
          fs.stat(path+'/'+file+'/clip.mp4', function (err, info){
            var day = info.mtime.getDate();
            var month = info.mtime.getMonth();
            var year = info.mtime.getFullYear();
            if (day < 10) {day = "0" + day;}
            if (month < 10) {month = "0" + month;}
            // Temp Date variable for compare them
            var tempDate = day + '-' + month + '-' + year;
            // I can see this console log it's working perfectly
            console.log('file date : ' + tempDate + ' FileName : ' + file);
            // Compare dates and if they are equal take that path to filesCollected Variable
            if (tempDate == '24-01-2018'){
              filesCollected += file + ';';
            // If i check this code block with console log it's working too.
            }
            // Last loop from this "Collected Files - OutsideIF" log is actually what 
            // i want. I put this for control code flow. But it's returning after 
            // "Collected Files :" console log below. So i can't return that data 
            console.log('Collected Files - OutsideIF : ' + filesCollected);
          });
          //end
        }
      }
    });
    //It's return empty because this code executing first. So i guess fs.stat is async
    console.log('Collected Files : ' + filesCollected);
  })
};
```

Comment: When you switched to `fs.statSync` did you also switch to using `var info = fs.statSync(path+'/'+file+'/clip.mp4');` instead of a callback? Sync I/O functions in general do not accept callbacks.

Comment: @Paulpro I update my code as you suggest and it's worked. I'm new to node js. Thank you so much for the tip! You can write it as a answer.

Comment: Okay, I converted my comment into an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you convert from [fs.stat](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_stat_path_callback) to [fs.statSync](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_statsync_path) you need to use its return value instead of passing in a callback. EG.

```
fs.stat(path, function (err, info){
  ...
} );
```

is approximately equivalent* to:

```
try {
  const info = fs.statSync(path);
  ...
} catch ( err ) {

}
```

<sub>*aside from the differences between asynchronous and synchronous,
 and using const means `info` can't be reassigned within the try block.</sub>